# How can I make sure that the entered input matches the array index in order to output the right solution?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, if-statement, methods

So basically, I am trying to output both the top film for a specific year and the total income that movies made that year. Both of my methods are not working correctly and I am especially having trouble in getting the year that was input to match with the year that the movies have in the arrays in order to output the total income and top film of that year.

For now my program outputs like so:

**
Enter a year from 1991 - 2018: 2016

Thank you received 2016

The total amount made for 2016 was $966.50

The greatest income made by a movie in 2016 was The Jungle Book at $966.50**

However, the total amount for 2016 is not $966.50 and the top 2016 movie is not The Jungle Book, it is Finding Dory...

Here is the `getInput.getUserInput()`

```
    public static int getUserInput(int minYear, int maxYear) {
        int year = 0;
        boolean keepLooping = true;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (keepLooping) {
            System.out.printf("\nEnter a year from %s - %s:", minYear, maxYear);
            year = input.nextInt();
            if (year < minYear || year > maxYear) {
                System.out.printf("Invalid entry . . .");
            } else {
                keepLooping = false;
            }
        }
        return year;
    }
```

Here is the class

```
        public class Films {
            private String filmTitle;
            private double filmIncome;
            private int premiereYear;

        Films(String title, double income, int year) {
            filmTitle = title;
            filmIncome = income;
            premiereYear = year;

        }

        public String getFilmTitle() {
            return filmTitle;
        }

        public void setFilmTitle(String filmTitle) {
            this.filmTitle = filmTitle;
        }

        public double getFilmIncome() {
            return filmIncome;
        }

        public void setFilmIncome(double filmIncome) {
            this.filmIncome = filmIncome;
        }

        public int getPremiereYear() {
            return premiereYear;
        }

        public void setPremiereYear(int premiereYear) {
            this.premiereYear = premiereYear;
        }

    }
```

Here is the file that runs the program

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Films[] f = new Films[8];
        f[0] = new Films("Frozen", 1290.0, 2013);
        f[1] = new Films("The Lion King", 968.4, 1994);
        f[2] = new Films("Zootopia", 1023.7, 2016);
        f[3] = new Films("Incredibles 2", 1240.3, 2018);
        f[4] = new Films("Finding Dory", 1028.5, 2016);
        f[5] = new Films("Shrek 2", 919.8, 2004);
        f[6] = new Films("The Jungle Book", 966.5, 2016);
        f[7] = new Films("Despicable Me 2", 970.7, 2013);

        int yearEntered = getInput.getUserInput(1991, 2018);
        System.out.printf("\nThank you received %s", yearEntered);

        Films total = getTotalIncome(f, yearEntered);
        System.out.printf("\nThe total amount made for %s was $%2.2f", yearEntered, total.getFilmIncome());

        Films top = getTopFilm(f, yearEntered);
        if (top == null) {
            System.out.printf("0");
        } else {
            System.out.printf("\nThe greatest income made by a movie in %s was %s at $%2.2f", yearEntered,
                    top.getFilmTitle(), top.getFilmIncome());
        }

    }

    private static Films getTotalIncome(Films[] f, int yearEntered) {
        Films totalIncome = null;
        double add = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            if (f[i].getPremiereYear() == yearEntered) {
                add += f[i].getFilmIncome();
                totalIncome = f[i];
            }

        }
        return totalIncome;

    }

    private static Films getTopFilm(Films[] f, int yearEntered) {
        Films topFilm = null;
        double max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            if (f[i].getPremiereYear() != yearEntered) {
                continue;
            }
            if (f[i].getFilmIncome() > max) {
                topFilm = f[i];
            }
        }
        return topFilm;
    }
```

Comment: _for a specific year_, and yet you're entering **two** years?

Comment: @zlakad The input should be within the range of 1991 and 2018. I entered 2016. Hence, "Thank you received **2016**.

Comment: you've some logical errors in `getTotalIncome` method. Since it's coded to return you the last film in the list while the value you wanted is computed and stored in the variable `add`. Also in `getTopFilm` method, the variable `max` is always 0, therefore will also return only the last film in the list. Hope this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in your max function.

```
private static Films getTopFilm(Films[] f, int yearEntered) {
        Films topFilm = null;
        double max = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
            if (f[i].getPremiereYear() != yearEntered) {
                continue;
            }
            if (f[i].getFilmIncome() > max) {
                topFilm = f[i];
                max = f[i].getFilmIncome(); // you forget to set the value of max.
            }
        }
        return topFilm;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Films[] f = new Films[8];
    f[0] = new Films("Frozen", 1290.0, 2013);
    f[1] = new Films("The Lion King", 968.4, 1994);
    f[2] = new Films("Zootopia", 1023.7, 2016);
    f[3] = new Films("Incredibles 2", 1240.3, 2018);
    f[4] = new Films("Finding Dory", 1028.5, 2016);
    f[5] = new Films("Shrek 2", 919.8, 2004);
    f[6] = new Films("The Jungle Book", 966.5, 2016);
    f[7] = new Films("Despicable Me 2", 970.7, 2013);

    int yearEntered = getInput.getUserInput(1991, 2018);
    System.out.printf("\nThank you received %s", yearEntered);
    Films total = getTotalIncome(f, yearEntered);
    System.out.printf("\nThe total amount made for %s was $%2.2f", yearEntered, total.getFilmIncome());
    Films top = getTopFilm(f, yearEntered, total.getFilmIncome());

    if (top == null) {
        System.out.printf("0");
    } else {
        System.out.printf("\nThe greatest income made by a movie in %s was %s at $%2.2f", yearEntered, top.getFilmTitle(), top.getFilmIncome());
    }
}

private static Films getTotalIncome(Films[] f, int yearEntered) { 
    Films totalIncome = null; 
    double add = 0; 
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE; 
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) { 
        if (f[i].getPremiereYear() == yearEntered && max < f[i].getFilmIncome()) { 
            max = f[i].getFilmIncome(); totalIncome = f[i]; 
        } 
    } 
    return totalIncome; 
} 

private static Films getTopFilm(Films[] f, int yearEntered,double total) { 
    Films topFilm = null; 
    double max = 0; 
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) { 
        if (f[i].getPremiereYear() != yearEntered) { 
            continue; 
        } 
        if (f[i].getFilmIncome() == total) { 
            topFilm = f[i]; 
            break;
        } 
    } 

    return topFilm; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Like Vivek said you have a problem in you max function

```
private static Films getTopFilm(Films[] f, int yearEntered) {
    Films topFilm = null;
    double max = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if (f[i].getFilmIncome() > max) {
            topFilm = f[i];
            //need to reset max here
            max = f[i].getFilmIncome();
        }
    }
    return topFilm;
}
```

but you also have a bug in your get `getTotalIncome` method as well:

```
private static double getTotalIncome(Films[] f, int yearEntered) {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < f.length; i++) {
        if (f[i].getPremiereYear() == yearEntered) {
            total += f[i].getFilmIncome();
        }
    }
    return total;
}
```

Im not sure why you were returning a `Film` object from there, what you wanted to do was iterate over the films summing up all movies from that year.

you would then edit your main function to call it as such

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ...
    double total = getTotalIncome(f, yearEntered);
    System.out.printf("\nThe total amount made for %s was $%2.2f", yearEntered, total);
    ...
}
```